# How to do reduce number of watchers in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a requirement where all the data have to be shown on the same page (so can't use pagination). I am working with angular 1.5 and following is the code :

```
<div ng-repeat="a in data">
    <span>{{a.help}}</span>
    <div ng-repeat="b in a.dataAgain">
        <span>{{b.helpAgain}}</span>
        <table class="table table-bordered" style="text-align:center;">
            <tr class="info">
                <td><strong>S.No.</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Age</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Id</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Dept</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="c in b.allData" class="info">
                <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                <td>{{c.name}}</td>
                <td>{{c.age}}</td>
                <td>{{c.id}}</td>
                <td>{{c.dept}}</td>
              </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my scenario the number of watchers reaches to around 1500 , i am using ng-stats [ng-stats](https://github.com/kentcdodds/ng-stats) for watching the number of watchers. Can anybody hep me how to reduce the number of watchers.

I found same question over here :
[Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355450/unable-to-reduce-the-number-of-watchers-in-ng-repeat)

But there is no proper answer for the same

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="a in data">
    <span>{{::a.help}}</span>
    <div ng-repeat="b in a.dataAgain">
        <span>{{::b.helpAgain}}</span>
        <table class="table table-bordered" style="text-align:center;">
            <tr class="info">
                <td><strong>S.No.</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Age</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Id</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Dept</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="c in b.allData" class="info">
                <td>{{::$index+1}}</td>
                <td>{{::c.name}}</td>
                <td>{{::c.age}}</td>
                <td>{{::c.id}}</td>
                <td>{{::c.dept}}</td>
              </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular processes the DOM as usual and once the value has been resolved it removes the particular property from it’s internal `$$watchers` list.

You can read more about it here: [More Broad Answer](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/speeding-up-angular-js-with-simple-optimizations/135)

Comment: It is giving error for ::, Syntax Error: Token ':' not a primary expression at column 1 of the expression ::a.help

Comment: The two `::` colons need to be next to each other. No spaces beween them.

Comment: @georgeawg, i am giving like {{::a.help}}, no spaces between them and it is giving error, can you help with the fiddle or something. It will behighly appreciated

Comment: Demo of One-Time Binding --  https://plnkr.co/edit/1M5vIDNtkOLSKiSIK2W4?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend using collection-repeat over ng-repeat it will dramatically improve application performance. Just give it a shot.

```
<div collection-repeat="b in a.dataAgain">
```

and

```
<tr collection-repeat="c in b.allData" class="info">
```

Comment: Collection repeat is related to ionic , i think??
I am not using ionic

Comment: You haven't mention in your question so I just assumed that.